# Como implementar una primary key en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**¿Que es mejor usar en rails para una primary key compuesta?**
Usar la gema composite_primary_keys? o usar un índice que contenga las columnas que necesito para la primary key?

**¿Cuál es la mejor manera de identificar de manera única una fila en una tabla?**, que contiene tres columnas, donde el valor de cada columna se puede repetir varias veces, pero la combinación de las tres columnas debe ser una combinación única.

**¿Qué ventaja tiene indexar las tres columnas de una fila de una tabla?**

*De antemano, muchas ¡Gracias!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Que es mejor usar en rails para una primary key compuesta?

Podrías utilizar la gema `composite_primary_keys`, pero no te recomiendo ir *en contra de la plataforma*; yo optaría por agregar un índice compuesto único (i.e. *unique constraint*) que contenga las columnas que necesitas y dejaría como llave primaria el autonumérico que genera *rails* por defecto.

> ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de identificar de manera única una fila en
>   una tabla?

Con `find_by` (en lugar de `find`) puedes obtener el registro único, especificando los valores de cada columna, por ejemplo:

```
Model.find_by(col_a: value_a, col_b: value_b, col_c: value_c)
```

> ¿Qué ventaja tiene indexar las tres columnas de una fila de una tabla?

El índice acelerará la búsqueda de registros, lo que hará que tu aplicación se desempeñe mejor.